# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str in Pandas alive

Tags: python, pandas, charts

I want to have a gif chart with pandas alive.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_alive as pda
import matplotlib.animation

df = pd.read_csv("price.csv", index_col="Geography")
table = df.T
table.plot_animated(kind='line',filename="priceOfhomesIncanada.gif",period_fmt="%Y",title="Price Of Homes In Canada From Q1 2017 To Q2 2021")
```

I got data from csv, even I tried with colab.
It works with default mode but doesn't with line mode.
I get type error and runtime error but I have all of the needed library.

Comment: How is the title of the question related? Is that the error you're getting?

Comment: yes and i can't debug it

Comment: I think you need to check the data in your dataset to check if all values are str, and if they're not, store them as str